# Bootstrap4 custom override - Expected !default flag for "$body-bg"

Tags: npm, bootstrap-4, lint

I have done a fresh install of bootstrap version 4.1.1

I created a custom.scss file and put the following in it (straight from bootstrap4 online docs)

```
// Your variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Bootstrap and its default variables
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

When I run `npm run dis`, i'm receiving the following error:

```
scss/custom.scss
2:1  ×  Expected !default flag for "$body-bg"      scss/dollar-variable-default
3:1  ×  Expected !default flag for "$body-color"   scss/dollar-variable-default
```

According to bootstraps documentation you must remove the "!default" but the error specifies you must have the "!default".

I'm assuming I'm overlooking something but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: I have customized those two properties in the same way. I mean without using `!default`.  But I do not use `node-modules`. I use `webjars`

Comment: Your lint is configured to expect the `!default` flag.

Comment: Does lint read a config file that's specifically for bootstrap? I have followed the bootstrap instructions, I'm not sure why my lint would be configured differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the default installation of bootstrap has a file called .stylelintrc. This is the configuration file for stylelint.

For some reason, the example given on bootstraps website is not in alignment to the default configuration of the .stylelintrc file.

You need to change the line

"scss/dollar-variable-default": [false, { "ignore": "local" }]

to

"scss/dollar-variable-default":null

In order to get their example working.